# Annotate every nth point on plot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I have the following code to annotate a plot made with matplotlib:

```
for i,j in data.items():
   ax.annotate(str(j), xy=(i, j))
```

This annotates every point on a very point dense plot. Is there anyway to only put an annotation or label on every nth point?

Comment: You could add an arbitrary counter that gets increased every iteration. And you put that `ax.annotate(...)` inside an `if counter % 50 == 0` to annotate every 50th point. The counter could be added manually or by using `enumerate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in my comment:

```
for count, (i,j) in enumerate(data.items()):
    if count % 50 == 0:
        ax.annotate(str(j), xy=(i, j))
```

Replace `50` with a different integer if you don't want to annotate every 50'th point.